# Встраиваемые языки и движки: уместны ли вопросы по ним?

Tags: обсуждение

Как известно, существуют встраиваемые языки вроде [lua](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua), которые встречаются в движках (как пример с тем же lua, [INSTEAD](http://instead.syscall.ru)). Данные движки имеют свои соглашения, т.е., по сути дела, являются диалектами. Как определить, уместен ли этот вопрос на сайте? Конкретно мне кажется, что вопрос уместен, если он не затрагивает особенности диалекта, или кратко их поясняет.

P. S.: по сути дела, arduino тоже является диалектом. Как быть с ним?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Не вижу проблем со встраиваемыми языками программирования: это всё равно вопросы о программировании, а значит, онтопик. (Ну или если вопрос плохой, то офтопик.)

Единственная проблема — если область применения конкретного языка (или, хуже того, конкретного диалекта) узка, то скорее всего не найдётся так много отвечающих на вопросы по этой тематике.

Comment: Lua достаточно популярен, кстати.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Это да, но у нас вроде нет штатных отвечающих по нему (покамест).

Comment: Даже если отвечающих мало или почти нет - пусть небольшое количество вопросов будет - проблемы в этом нет.

Comment: @VladD, у нас вообще из _штатных_ один николас :)

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, это было в переносном смысле. Думаю, что знаю у нас по крайней мере «штатного» рубиста :)